# C# - String to String with Array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

```
string[,] data = new string[26, 2] { { "a", "00-" }, { "b", "01-" }, { "c", "02-" }, { "d", "03-" }, { "e", "04-" }, { "f", "05-" }, { "g", "06-" },
            { "h", "07-" }, { "i", "08-" }, { "j", "09-" }, { "k", "10-" }, { "l", "11-" }, { "m", "12-" }, { "n", "13-" }, { "o", "14-" }, { "p", "15-" },
            { "q", "16-" }, { "r", "17-" }, { "s", "18-" }, { "t", "19-" }, { "u", "20-" }, { "v", "21-" }, { "w", "22-" }, { "x", "23-" }, { "y", "24-" }, { "z", "25-" } };

            string dataIn;

            Console.Write("In: ");
            dataIn = Console.ReadLine();
            dataIn.ToLower();
```

For example if I write 'abc' in dataIn, how can i transform it to '00-01-02-'?

Comment: Already tried to do with only one char (it worked), and tried to split the string into a char array.. but I'm kinda newbie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier if you use a `Dictionary<char, string>` instead.

```
var data = new Dictionary<char,string>();
data.Add('a', "00-");
...

dataIn = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
var result = string.Concat(dataIn.Select(x => data[x]));
```